# Does the plastic cup PETE 1 material leak toxic material if subject to boiling water even for part of a minute?

Tags: plastics

Sometimes a cafe may pour boiling tea into a plastic cup made of PETE 1 and then add lemon and cold water / ice to it.  When the cup is handed to the customer, the cup looks ok.  And I suppose even if a person drinks such drinks for a few years, and gets cancer, what proof do you have that it is due to the cup?   The cafe doesn't really care, because money, profits, and speed is of the utmost importance in the country.

For PETE 1 plastic, when it is subject to boiling, 100°C, water or tea for 30 seconds or 1-2 minutes, will it already leak out toxic chemicals?

Comment: PETE? Do you mean PETP (sometimes PET)?

Comment: I saw the PETE 1 and PET 1 are the same

Comment: #1 is the recycling number for the plastic.